# Disable ssl check globally in python 2.7.10 - Pycontrol

Tags: python, ssl

Please suggest a way to disable certificate verification check globally in this scenario where I don't know how to pass a ssl context.

```
import pycontrol.pycontrol as pc

b = pc.BIGIP(
hostname = "xx.xx.xx.xx",
username = "xxxxxxx",
password = "xxxxxxx",
fromurl = True,
wsdls = ['GlobalLB.WideIP','GlobalLB.Pool']
)

<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)>
```

With version below 2.7.6 it works fine, but I would like to know how to make it work in 2.7.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this one fixed on 2.7.10 by using a custom suds client:

```
import urllib2
import ssl
from suds import transport
from suds.client import Client
from suds.xsd.doctor import Import, ImportDoctor
from pycontrol import pycontrol

IMP = Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
DOCTOR = ImportDoctor(IMP)
ICONTROL_URI = '/iControl/iControlPortal.cgi'
SESSION_WSDL = 'System.Session'

class HTTPSUnVerifiedCertTransport(transport.https.HttpAuthenticated):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        transport.https.HttpAuthenticated.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def u2handlers(self):
        handlers = []
        handlers.append(urllib2.ProxyHandler(self.proxy))
        handlers.append(urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(self.pm))
        # python ssl Context support - PEP 0466
        if hasattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context'):
            ssl_context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
            handlers.append(urllib2.HTTPSHandler(context=ssl_context))
        else:
            handlers.append(urllib2.HTTPSHandler())
        return handlers

def new_get_suds_client(self, url, **kw):
        if not url.startswith('https'):
            t = transport.http.HttpAuthenticated(username=self.username,
                                                 password=self.password)
            c = Client(url, transport=t, username=self.username,
                         password=self.password, doctor=DOCTOR, **kw)
        else:
            t = HTTPSUnVerifiedCertTransport(username=self.username,
                                             password=self.password)
            c = Client(url, transport=t, username=self.username,
                         password=self.password, doctor=DOCTOR, **kw)
        return c

pycontrol.BIGIP._get_suds_client = new_get_suds_client
b = pycontrol.BIGIP(
    hostname = "xx.xx.xx.xx",
    username = "xxxxxxx",
    password = "xxxxxxx",
    fromurl = True,
    wsdls = ['GlobalLB.WideIP','GlobalLB.Pool']
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem introduced with 2.7.9, and in my situation of only scripting against intranet sites (which I have *zero* chance of getting full certs installed into) I have taken the simplistic approach of staying with 2.7.8.

Comment: looks like before 2.7.8 , it will work fine with the default behavior. Post that you have to use a custom suds client to make it work. Anyways thanks for the reply :)